# I get this error while making my first program: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to dive into swift a little bit and started trying to make something simple and I keep getting this error: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I've looked around on here and google and tried what they told me to do and it doesn't work and I feel stupid af.

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Glibc

print("How much did you spend today: ")
if let input = Int(readLine()!){
    print("You have spent", input)
}
else{
    print("The input is not a number")
}
```

Comment: `readLine()` returns a `nil` value. Why? That's a good question. What's `readLine()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.journaldev.com/19612/swift-readline-swift-print
is a good tutorial for newbies to do the first steps...

Try this:

```
import Foundation
import Glibc

print("How much did you spend today: ")
if let input = readLine(){

    if let intputInt = Int(input) {
    print("You have spent", inputInt)
    }
    else {
       print("The input is not a number")
    }
}
else{
    print("The input is not valid")
}
```

Comment: Why not vote to close as a duplicate, what does this answer add?

Comment: Sorry, just answered the question ... you are right it's a duplicate ..